# No sound (Driver: N/A) in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: sound

I just install ubuntu 20.4 on my laptop. But the output device sound in setting is "dummy output", no other selection. The result I get after command "inxi -SMA" is "driver N/A". How I can fix it?

```
 $ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: hieunguyen-Swift3 Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.7 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Acer product: Swift SF314-54 v: V1.16 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: KBL model: Strongbow_KL v: V1.16 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Insyde v: 1.16 date: 05/30/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: N/A 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-48-generic
```

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 20.4 I can guess it is 20.04?

Comment: You right, its the Ubuntu 20.04 on my system